# CSS horizontal scroller, how to position "below" before "right"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

### QUESTION

I've been searching a while and can't figure out how I should go about implementing a horizontal scroller.

This is my scroll area

```
_____________
|           |
|___________|
```

Scroll area with two cards

```
_____________
|__|        |
|__|________|
```

Scroll area with four cards, etc

```
_____________
|__|__|     |
|__|__|_____|
```

Is there any way to implement this with `position:relative;` on the cards? I figure the container should have `width:auto;` but how can I get the next card to fall below, rather than to the right?

### ANSWER

[CSS horizontal scroller, how to position "below" before "right"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847007/css-horizontal-scroller-how-to-position-below-before-right/31866691#31866691)

Comment: Can you please show your code effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, requires `flex-flow: column wrap` with `display: flex` and `align-content: left`

```css
#deck {
    flex-flow:column wrap;
    display:flex;
    align-content:left;
  
    height:204px;
    width:250px;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:grey;
}

.card {
    background-color:white;
    margin:1px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="deck">
    <div class="card">1</div>
    <div class="card">2</div>
    <div class="card">3</div>
    <div class="card">4</div>
    <div class="card">5</div>
    <div class="card">6</div>
</div>
```

Margin doesn't seem to be affecting right side, but the layout looks good

http://jsfiddle.net/kcxnany7/1/

Answer (score 0):

I know its a little bit messy but, I think you could do something like this...

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
</div>
<button id="ad">add div</button>
```

css:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Red.svg/120px-Red.svg.png);
}
div.wrap{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
div.top{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    max-height:50%;
    top: 0; left:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
div.top > div{
    position:relative;
    width:40px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    display: inline-block;
}
div.bottom{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    max-height:50%;
    bottom: 0; left:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
div.bottom > div{
    position:relative;
    width:40px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    display: inline-block;
}
button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 9999999999999;
}
```

js:

```
var cCount = true;

$('#ad').click(function () {
    if (cCount) {
        $('.top').append('<div></div>');
        $('.top').animate({width: $('.top').find('div').length * 40 + 'px'}, 1);
        cCount = !cCount;
    } else {
        $('.bottom').append('<div></div>');
        $('.bottom').animate({width: $('.bottom').find('div').length * 40 + 'px'}, 1);
        cCount = !cCount;
    }
});
```

You can also check it out [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/f5sw51pv/)

Comment: sorry man, this is too complex, using absolute positioning, and jquery